# Best approach to manage a List<String> variable throughout session in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring MVC 3.2.4 to design a web based application. As per the requirement, (using Tiles view) Employee Name as hyperlink will be displayed on left side of the web page and on clicking them, right side will display Employee's details. There are other CRUD operations/forms exists like adding a new employee, deleting them and modify records.

Therefore, Employee Name will always be displayed on left side of Tiles view just like a (dynamic) menu. My question is how this `List<String> employeeName` be managed in Spring so that it should be available throughout a session? Should ModelAttribute, Cookie or anything else be used?

As of now, I have implemented this with @ModelAttribute but `List<String> employeeName` is being appeared in URL, therefore, I am planning of using Cookies.

Need your kind advise on what should be the best practice/approach for handling such situations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to access session is through `HttpSession` handler method argument. Set it once

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some-url/{someArg}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void someMethod(@PathVariable String someArg, HttpSession session) {    
     List<String> employeeName = getEmployees();
     session.setAttribute("employees", employeeName);
}
```

And then you can use it in other methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some-other-url/{someArg}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String someOtherMethod(@PathVariable String someArg, HttpSession session) {    
     List<String> employeeName = (List<String>)session.getAttribute("employees");
}
```

**Note:** there is significant downsides in the design decision to store employees identifiers in session:

1. Creation/deletion of employee by one user is not reflected for other users automatically as session is stored per application user.
2. Creation/deletion of employee requires modification of stored list in session.
3. Each application user has own session and hence own list of employees stored in session and if the number employees and users is large application would require more memory.

Comment: What about Cookies? I have never worked on them, so can that be used?

Comment: I believe that passing List<String> using Model in RequestParam will be costly as use will be clicking on VIEW link many a time and every time a `select name from employee` will be hit a database.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I implemented using Sessions and the `List<String> employeeName` values are not coming on URL. In case if you have time, can you please advise if same can be done by using Cookies? Their advantage and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `List<String>` throughout the session then use `request.getSession.setAttribute("employees", employeeName);`

With this, you can get employee name list anywhere until you invalidate the session.